# -bash: cd: ./pgsql: Catalog or file not found

Tags: 16.04, command-line, server

Why this happening?

```
user@server01:~$ ls
pqsql  sources
user@server01:~$ cd ./pgsql
-bash: cd: ./pgsql: Catalog or file not found
user@server01:~$ cd /home/user/pgsql
-bash: cd: /home/user/pgsql: Catalog or file not found
user@server01:~$ ls /home/user/
pqsql  sources
```

I can use sources:

```
user@server01:~$ cd ./sources/
user@server01:~/sources$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `pqsql`, there is the letter `q` (Q), not `g` (G).

You can write just the beginning of the path in a command (e.g. `cd ./p`), then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and the shell will [complete the correct name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion) for you.

Comment: i cant rep up until own 15 rep points. Thanks

Comment: Also,  you do not have to type ./  Just `cd pqsql` will work .